# GroovyUtils namespace two same <tag>

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have the code like:

```
def updateValueNode(testStepName, nameSpace, nodeName, val)
    groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
            holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(testStepName);
            holder.namespaces[("ns")] = nameSpace;;
            return  holder.getNodeValue("//ns:" + nodeName) as String;
```

And xml like:

```
<User>
<userName>UserOne</userName>
</User>
<User>
<userName>UserTwo</userName>
</User>
```

How can I get second user UserTwo with  the code?

First one I fecth like:

```
updateValueNode("DoStep#Request", "http://ls.ru/shh/dto/action", "UserName", context.getUserName() as String)
```

Comment: Do not have exact context where & how it is needed. From the method name in the description, assuming that you were trying to update value of second element `userName`. May be you want to try with properties, see http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing last line of method to (getNodeValue -> getNodeValue**s**, String -> String[]):

```
return  holder.getNodeValues("//ns:" + nodeName) as String[];
```

Then, `updateValueNode(...)[0]` - will give you the first result, `updateValueNode(...)[1]` - the second result, etc.

---

**Added:**

Another option, is to use `position` property in xpath. Like `/a/b/c[position()=1]`.

Example:

```
def updateValueNode(testStepName, nameSpace, nodeName, index)
    groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
            holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(testStepName);
            holder.namespaces[("ns")] = nameSpace;;
            return  holder.getNodeValue("//ns:" + nodeName + "[position()="+index+"]") as String;
```

Should work like:

```
updateValueNode(..., 1) - first one
updateValueNode(..., 2) - second one
etc.
```

Comment: But can I do this with soupui xpath/? Not to change code of method??

Comment: Updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: I know but I can not change method

Comment: Well, this method returns the **first** found result. That's it. You can not force it to return second found result. Therefore, you either change this method, or write a new method which I wrote in my post, or inline the method I wrote in my post. There are no other options.